# Swift static table view disappears when connected to table view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I have created a simple static table view in my main storyboard but every time I hook up a blank UITableViewController the static view is not loading.

[image: It should look like this (no controller file connected)]
[image: When connected it looks like this]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the default implementations of `numberOfSectionsInTableView()` and `tableView(numberOfRowsInSection:)` from your UITableViewController subclass.

i.e. remove those methods because they return 0:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: wow, cool solution ! have been trying various options like deleting the VC, deleting the navigation item, bar button items etc n number of times. Thanks !

Comment: This solution is perfect ... I used to hate Static Cells but now am happy